# Library not loaded before `doJavaScript` when not main request

Tags: wt

I'm trying to delay the construction of every 'page' (i.e. a `Wt::WWidget` inside my global `Wt::WStackedWidget`), until it is needed. Therefore I'm using a method similar to the [`DeferredWidget`](https://github.com/emweb/wt/blob/master/examples/widgetgallery/DeferredWidget.h#L17) of the Widget Gallery example of Wt.

However, when I load a library using `require`, the execution of javascript code is not delayed until the library is loaded, when the content is not loaded with the first request (f.ex. inside `WWidget::load()`), i.e. running the following code

```
wApp->require("myLibrary.js"); // defines function MyFunction ();
doJavaScript ("MyFunction ();");
```

runs without error when it is requested on the first loaded page, but when the content is loaded after a user event, the following javascript error occurs:

> MyFunction is not defined

**Question:** How should I overcome this error *or* how should I correctly delay the loading of my (large) javascript library until needed?

**Further research**

Inspecting the source code of `WebRenderer::collectJS`:

Javascript updates seems to be performed before loading new libraries:

```
// Executing javascript updates, including doJavaScript calls.
for (unsigned i = 0; i < changes.size(); ++i) {
  changes[i]->asJavaScript(sout, DomElement::Priority::Update);
  delete changes[i];
}

...

// Loading new libraries.
int librariesLoaded = loadScriptLibraries(*js, app);
```

Shouldn't the javascript update being delayed until the new libraries are loaded?

**Further research - Part 2**

Executing javascript code (which may depend on required libraries) is delayed at two different places, i.e. inside

- `WebRenderer::collectJavaScript`: delays execution of all javascript code (including invisible changes) until all **old** required libraries (excluding newly required libraries f.ex. inside `WWidget::load`) are loaded.
- `WebRenderer::collectJS`: delays execution of **some** javascript code until all required libraries (including newly required libraries f.ex. inside `WWidget::load`) are loaded.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Perhaps you're using `require` inside of `load` or `render`?

Comment: @RockinRoel I indeed use `require` inside `load`, to allow deferred creation of a Widget as done in `DeferredWidget` of the widgetgallery example. Is that not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with the javascript scriploader behavior. But in my wt experience i make it append in this way.

1) My javascript library is load in my main page at start with require.

2) If i need later some new function, i write it in my script string like this :

```
string javacode = "function MyTest ( ) { "
                      "alert('test') ; }"
                      "MyTest();"   
doJavaScript ( javacode ) ;
```

Comment: I try to avoid loading unneeded libraries at startup.It slows down the initial page load and it made my C++ classes less straight forward as I have to remember to include the necessary libraries in my main page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want load some javascript file and run some function after it is load you schould make the require in the contructor of your container class.

Then you derived the function bool Wt::WCompositeWidget::loaded()
and put in this function your dojavaScript...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the difference with your previous answer? You probably want me to  construct my container class at startup, which may require a large js file to load (which I do not want). Or could I delay the construction of the container class? If I do so, I probably run into the same problem. Note that I want to delay the construction of all pages as it is done in the Widget Gallery by using `DeferredWidget`. Could you give an example where the js library is not loaded at startup?

Comment: I edited the introduction of my question to make it more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: The solution 1) is so i recommand, you load all your javascrit at start and use then when you will. If your javascript files are to big, than means that not use enought the wt solutions..

Comment: The solution 2) is more in your way, you create your container when you will, and load in the constructor of your new container  your javscript files. When your container is totaly load, the function loaded will be automaticaly be run by Wt, you just to derived it and do what you want

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm afraid solution 2 doesn't work (as I want), because when I delay the construction of my container class until needed (i.e. shown), the constructor and loaded method are called inside the same request (between browser and Wt server), resulting in the same error. Could you construct an example?